# CI Filter to create Black & White image?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have a CIImage I need to convert from color to Black and White within my Cocoa / objective C program.  Peter H. previously pointed me to this link http://www.codingadventures.com/2008/06/threshold-filter-in-glsl/ as a potential solution ... but I am having trouble compiling the kernel routine there (see separate thread, if interested).

So I am wondering if one of the other built-in CIFilters will accomplish what I'm trying to do.  I don't want a grayscale image ... I want each pixel in the Result image to be either Black or White -- I just need to be able to tell the filter how to determine which pixels should become black and which should become white.  The "Threshold" filter in Photoshop does exactly this -- it lets me specify the "threshold" and then it uses this value to decide which pixels become white and which become black.  This is what I am trying to "replicate" via code in my Xcode project.

Any ideas if one of the other built in filters can be used for this?  Thanks.

Comment: How about a link to the separate thread about the kernel routine?

Comment: Here's a link to the other thread:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2963218/applying-transformations-to-nsbitmapimagerep

Follow the hyperlink behind "threshold filter"

Comment: Quartz Composer is a great place to experiment with Core Image filters.  I used it to test the threshold filter given by the link.  There was one compile error, caused by what appeared to be a minus sign but was actually an en-dash character.  Once I fixed that, it worked.

Comment: I cannot get the kernel routine from that other thread to compile, either.  See this thread where I have asked for help on that:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3107274/compiler-error-on-vec4-kernel-routine

The compiler error is basically why I am asking "is there another way to do this" in the first place!  When I first pasted the kernel code I had that same "en-dash" issue you describe.  I found and fixed that, but also have a different compiler error which I cannot figure out.  :(

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best Core Image filter to produce black and white effects?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10030631/what-is-the-best-core-image-filter-to-produce-black-and-white-effects)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the [CIColorMap filter](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIColorMap). 
Give it a 20(w) by 1(h) jpg where the left half is white and the right half is black (or the other way around) and use that as your color map gradient. That seems to hammer down the colors nicely. I originally tried a 2x1 image with 1 white pixel and one black, but it looked like it got interpolated a bit. I went up to 20x1 and it worked fine.

Hint: I used Core Image Funhouse (not Quartz Composer) to experiment.

Comment: Hmmm.  I have been playing around with the technique you suggested and it is not producing the results I expect.  I have tried 1x2 black-white & white-black (swapping the order) --- and 1x20 black-white & white-black.  Is there any online documentation available that describes how the gradient map should work?  Or examples?

Comment: Post the code you're using to set all this up. Works fine in Core Image Fun House, which is just a basic GUI wrapper to tryout the existing CI filters.

Comment: After additional experimentation I think the issue may be with my source Image gradient filter, rather than my code.  Using FunHouse, if I apply my gradient filter to the included Copenhagen.jpg image ... it does exactly what I want.  If, however, I apply the same filter to my own image (the one I need to modify in my program) ... it does not behave the same way.  The transformation makes my image either completely white or completely black (depending on whether the left side of my 1x20 gradient is white or black).  to be cont'd...

Comment: I created the gradient filter using Photoshop. It is an 8bit RGB file, White background, 72 ppi resolution, 1hx20w size. Color profile defaulted to sRGB IEC61966-2.1. I created the data by selecting the left 10 pixels then using Edit/Fill; Black (or white), blend mode normal and opacity 100%. Then did the other color on the right-hand pixels. Then saved the file as JPG with Image Quality = 8 (default) & baseline "standard". Would any of that cause an issue? If it works for Copenhagen, wonder why it would NOT work for my image (which came from my iphone)? Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: Oops ... on the second-to-last comment I meant to say "... with my source image OR my gradient filter ...", on the first sentence.  But my ability to edit comment 1 evidently went away when I posted comment 2.

Comment: The best advice I can give here is to look into the details of both of your images. Bit depth, color space, format, etc. This approach worked alright for both the Funhouse example images and screen captured images (which I used to generate a quick test image).

Comment: OK.  Well, thanks for the help on this.  The filter DOES do what I want -- just not with my particular image!  Hopefully with some additional investigation I can figure that out.  Meanwhile I'll mark this thread Answered and if I have more issues post them in a new thread.  Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 6):

Took some time to figure out the code for CIColorMap so i wanted to post this. Joshua has the answer above. This is just an example of implementation...

```
CIImage *beginImage = [CIImage imageWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"wedding" ofType:@"jpg"]]];
CIImage *inputGradientImage = [CIImage imageWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"grad" ofType:@"png"]]];
CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIColorMap" keysAndValues:kCIInputImageKey, beginImage, @"inputGradientImage",inputGradientImage, nil];
CIImage *outputImage = [filter outputImage];
CGImageRef cgimg = [context createCGImage:outputImage fromRect:[outputImage extent]];
UIImage *newImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgimg];
self.imageView.image = newImage;
CGImageRelease(cgimg);
```

Answer (score 5):

Many solutions on the internet create grayscale values. There is no need for filters. If you need such than use code such as

```
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray();
CGImageRef greyImage = CGImageCreateCopyWithColorSpace(backingImage, colorSpace);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
```

Proper threshold filter follows: 
inputThreshold can be float value from 0.0f to 0.5f

https://gist.github.com/xhruso00/a3f8a9c8ae7e33b8b23d

Detailed recipe can be found at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_custom_filters/ci_custom_filters.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001185-CH6-CJBEDHHH

Multiple metallibs depending on target [Compile each .metal file into a separate .metallib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54914564/compile-each-metal-file-into-a-separate-metallib)

Metal file (fast math iOS12+)

```
#include <metal_stdlib>
using namespace metal;

//https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_monochrome_and_RGB_palettes

//https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_luminance
//https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grayscale
constant half3 kRec709Luma  = half3(0.2126, 0.7152, 0.0722);
constant half3 kRec601Luma  = half3(0.299 , 0.587 , 0.114);
//constant float3 kRec2100Luma = float3(0.2627, 0.6780, 0.0593);

#include <CoreImage/CoreImage.h>

extern "C" { namespace coreimage {

    half lumin601(half3 p)
    {
        return dot(p.rgb, kRec601Luma);
    }

    half lumin709(half3 p)
    {
        return dot(p.rgb, kRec709Luma);
    }

    half4 thresholdFilter(sample_h image, half threshold)
    {
        half4 pix = unpremultiply(image);
        half luma = lumin601(pix.rgb);
        pix.rgb = half3(step(threshold, luma));
        return premultiply(pix);
    }
}}
```

Objective-C file

```
#import "CIFilter+BlackAndWhiteThresholdFilter.h"
#include <objc/runtime.h>
#import <CoreImage/CoreImageDefines.h>
#import <Metal/Metal.h>

@class BlackAndWhiteThresholdFilter;

static NSString *const kCIInputThreshold = @"inputThreshold";
NSString *const kBlackAndWhiteThresholdFilterName = @"BlackAndWhiteThreshold";
static NSString *const kBlackAndWhiteThresholdFilterDisplayName = @"Black & White Threshold";

@implementation CIFilter(BlackAndWhiteThresholdFilter)

@dynamic inputImage;
@dynamic threshold;

+ (CIFilter<BlackAndWhiteThreshold>*) blackAndWhiteThresholdFilter
{
    [BlackAndWhiteThresholdFilter class]; //kick off initialize to register filter
    CIFilter<BlackAndWhiteThreshold>*filter = (CIFilter<BlackAndWhiteThreshold>*)[CIFilter filterWithName:kBlackAndWhiteThresholdFilterName];
    static dispatch_once_t oncePredicate;
    dispatch_once(&oncePredicate, ^{
        /// convenience removing input keyword
        class_addMethod([self class], @selector(threshold), (IMP)floatGetter, "f@:");
        class_addMethod([self class], @selector(setThreshold:), (IMP)floatSetter, "v@:f");
    });
    return filter;
}

static float floatGetter(id self, SEL _cmd) {

    NSString *selector = NSStringFromSelector(_cmd);
    ///capitalize first letter
    NSString *firstLetter = [[selector substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 1)] uppercaseString];
    NSString *key = [@"input" stringByAppendingString:[selector stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0, 1) withString:firstLetter]];
    id value = [self valueForKey:key];
    float number = NAN;
    if (value && [value isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]) {
        number = [value floatValue];
    }
    return number;
}

static void floatSetter(id self, SEL _cmd, float value) {
    NSString *selector = NSStringFromSelector(_cmd);
    NSString *aaa = [selector stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0, 3) withString:@"input"];
    [self setValue:@(value) forKey:[aaa substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, [aaa length] - 1)]];
}


@end

@interface BlackAndWhiteThresholdFilter()
{
    CIColorKernel *_kernel;
}
@end

@implementation BlackAndWhiteThresholdFilter

//more https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_image_units/ci_image_units.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001185-CH7-SW8
+ (void)initialize
{
    //verify registration with [CIFilter filterNamesInCategories:@[kCICategoryVideo]]
    //registering class responsible for CIFilter execution
    [CIFilter registerFilterName:kBlackAndWhiteThresholdFilterName
                     constructor:(id <CIFilterConstructor>)self //self means class BlackAndWhiteThresholdFilter
                 classAttributes:@{
                     kCIAttributeFilterCategories: @[
                             kCICategoryVideo,
                             kCICategoryStillImage,
                             kCICategoryCompositeOperation,
                             kCICategoryInterlaced,
                             kCICategoryNonSquarePixels
                     ],
                     kCIAttributeFilterDisplayName: kBlackAndWhiteThresholdFilterDisplayName,

                 }];
}


+ (CIFilter *)filterWithName:(NSString *)aName
{
    return [[self alloc] init];
}

- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {

        BOOL supportsMetal;

#if TARGET_OS_IOS
        supportsMetal = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice() != nil; //this forces GPU on macbook to switch immediatelly
#else
        supportsMetal = [MTLCopyAllDevices() count] >= 1;
#endif

        if (@available(macOS 10.13, *)) {

            //10.13 there are macbooks without metal + other forced installations
            if (supportsMetal) {
                _kernel = [self metalKernel];
            } else {
                _kernel = [self GLSLKernel];
            }

        } else {
            _kernel = [self GLSLKernel];
        }

        if (_kernel == nil) return nil;
    }

    return self;
}

- (CIColorKernel *)metalKernel
{

    NSURL *URL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"default" withExtension:@"metallib"]; //default is
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:URL];
    NSError *error;
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"%@", error);
    }
    return [CIColorKernel kernelWithFunctionName:@"thresholdFilter" fromMetalLibraryData:data error:&error];
}

- (CIColorKernel *)GLSLKernel //OpenGL Shading Language
{
    // WWDC 2017 510 - disadvanage is that this needs to be compiled on first run (performance penalty)
    NSString *kernelString = [self colorKernelText];
    return [CIColorKernel kernelWithString:kernelString]; // to suppress warning define CI_SILENCE_GL_DEPRECATION in pre-processor macros
}

- (NSString *)colorKernelText
{
    return
    @""
    "float lumin601(vec3 p)"
    "{"
    "  return dot(p, vec3(0.299 , 0.587 , 0.114));"
    "}"
    ""
    "kernel vec4 thresholdFilter(__sample image, float inputThreshold)"
    "{"
    "  vec4 src = unpremultiply( image) );"
    "  float luma = lumin601( src.rgb );"
    "  src.rgb = vec3( step( inputThreshold, luma));"
    "  return premultiply(src);"
    "}";
}

//kept for reference purpose 
- (NSString *)oldNonColorKernelText
{
    return
    @""
    "float lumin601(vec3 p)"
    "{"
    "  return dot(p, vec3(0.299 , 0.587 , 0.114));"
    "}"
    ""
    "kernel vec4 thresholdFilter(sampler image, float inputThreshold)"
    "{"
    "  vec4 src = unpremultiply( sample(image, samplerCoord(image)) );"
    "  float luma = lumin601( src.rgb );"
    "  src.rgb = vec3( step( inputThreshold, luma));"
    "  return premultiply(src);"
    "}";
}

- (NSArray *)inputKeys {
    return @[kCIInputImageKey, kCIInputThreshold];
}

- (NSArray *)outputKeys {
    return @[kCIOutputImageKey];
}

// ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------
#pragma mark - CIFilter Protocol

+ (NSDictionary *)customAttributes
{
    NSDictionary *inputThreshold = @{
                                         kCIAttributeType: kCIAttributeTypeScalar,
                                         kCIAttributeMin: @0.0f,
                                         kCIAttributeMax: @1.0f,
                                         kCIAttributeIdentity : @0.00,
                                         kCIAttributeDefault: @0.5f,
                                         };

    return @{
             kCIInputThreshold : inputThreshold,
             // This is needed because the filter is registered under a different name than the class.
             kCIAttributeFilterName : kBlackAndWhiteThresholdFilterName
             };
}

- (CIImage *)outputImage {

    CIImage *inputImage = [self inputImage];

    if ([self inputImage] == nil) {
        return nil;
    }

    CIImage *outputImage;

    outputImage = [_kernel applyWithExtent:[inputImage extent]
                               roiCallback:^CGRect(int index, CGRect destRect) { return destRect; }
                                 arguments:@[inputImage, [self inputThreshold]]];

    return outputImage;
}

@end
```

Updated with visual difference between black&white(left) and grayscale(right)

[image]

Comment: "There is no need for filters." Your solution *uses* filters. What am I missing?

Comment: You are right. I expressed myself bit wrongly. First three lines with the "CGImageCreateCopyWithColorSpace" are to create grayscale image which is what many solutions around the internet do. The code below is the CIFilter to create proper black white image according to the threshold values.