# Convert NSImage to binary image (1-bit)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsimage

How can I 'binarize' an NSImage (or an NSBitmapImageRep if that's a better approach)?

I understand the concept of thresholding an image to turn it into a 1-bit image. I don't know, though, whether this are already methods/functions to do this to an NSImage, or whether I must manually iterate over the pixels, and deal with each pixel.

Answer (score 1):

There are Core Image filters designed for this; check out the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3126340/ci-filter-to-create-black-white-image).