# Water Effect in SpriteKit using blur and threshold

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, cifilter

I am trying to make a water effect using SpriteKit similar to the answer in this link. [Water physics](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/97649/spritekit-water-flowing)

How can I add a blur effect and some sort of "threshold" filter to get that look?

I got the blur to work like this, but am not sure how to add a "threshold" filter.

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    let effectNode = SKEffectNode()

    let circleOne = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "circle1")
    circleOne.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) - 20, CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))

    let circleTwo = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "circle1")
    circleTwo.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) + 40, CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))

    effectNode.filter = blur()

    effectNode.addChild(circleOne)
    effectNode.addChild(circleTwo)

    addChild(effectNode)
}

func blur() -> CIFilter {
    let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIGaussianBlur")
    filter!.setDefaults()
    filter!.setValue(NSNumber(float: 10.0), forKey: "inputRadius")
    return filter!
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Look at this project. https://github.com/ymc-thzi/ios8-spritekit-custom-shader/tree/master/ios8-spritekit-custom-shader

Comment: Nobody knows what your definition of water effect is.

Comment: You'll find a threshold filter [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3126340/ci-filter-to-create-black-white-image), but I suspect that's not what you'll need to create the effect in the link you provided. It's looks more like a maximum-in-a-region operation.

Comment: The effect linked to in the post you link to took 10 seconds to render one frame at one point. You don't expect to render a similar effect @ 60FPS *with* a CIFilter on top on a mobile device, do you?

Comment: sorry @ElTomato, I probably should have mentioned the link that was posted in the answer.  This should help clear it up... http://www.patrickmatte.com/stuff/physicsLiquid/

Comment: @CloakedEddy the OP is referring to a different effect. See the above comment. It's definitely doable in Sprite Kit.

Answer (score 0):

So I found this Threshold filter that seems to work pretty well.

```
void main() {
lowp vec4 color = texture2D(u_texture,v_tex_coord);

if(color.w > 0.1) {
    color = vec4(251.0/255.0, 246.0/255.0, 0.0/255.0, 1.0);
} else {
    color = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
}

gl_FragColor = color; }
```

The frame rate is fairly terrible when I reach about 30-50 sprites colliding with each other unfortunately.

In order to help out a little, I got rid of the blur and just made the actual sprite images blurred, but it didn't help too much.

I did some [reading](http://blog.element84.com/comparing-sprite-kit-physics-to-direct-box2d.html) about SpriteKit's Box2d implementation, and unfortunately it seems to not be very efficient, so I might be stuck with it.

If anyone has a better solution, I'd love to hear your thoughts!

Here's what its looking like so far.

[image]