# converting image to binary in swift

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uiimage, core-graphics

I want to convert an image to binary black and white, at the moment I am looping through pixels (stored in UnsafeMutableBufferPointer) using normal nested loops, comparing each RGB to average and setting it to black or white, however.

This seems really slow and I am sure there is a built in a way that uses gpu or is well optimized. If you could provide a code sample or link it'd be great.

```
for var y in 0..<height {
    for var x in 0..<width{
        //Pixel is small class i made for 8 bit access and comparison
        if (Buffer[x+y*width]  < AVRRGB) {
            Buffer[x+y*width] = Pixel(RGB: 0x000000FF)
        } else{
            Buffer[x+y*width] = Pixel(RGB: 0xFFFFFFFF)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree with your last statement that there should be some existing lib to do this operation, preferably using the GPU, but a "think about"-note nonetheless: you currently access the pixels in a non-sequential manner. When working with performance critical applications (such as image processing), always make sure to access memory sequentially in the same sequence it is stored. Since your buffer is (seemingly) just a long array, you should read and write its elements in sequence.

Comment: Check out [these search results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bios%5d%20uiimage%20convert%20black%20white).

Comment: Do not needlessly use tags. This question has absolutely nothing to do with Xcode. Please read a tag's description before using it.

Comment: @dfri good point, though for for example 5 by 5 pixel image it would be 25 pixel array and I am going through it as  0 1 2 3 4 5 5+0 =6 7 8 ... could you elaborate what you mean by accessing sequentially?

Comment: @rmaddy I have, most fit in CIFilters, but I had no luck applying it to my case.  also sorry for the tag

Comment: Again, some existing lib should be used for this task, but for the technical discussion only: if you are indeed accessing as 0, 1, 2, ..., you are doing it sequentially (as the buffer is just an array), but it's good to think about in case you are working with matrices (which depends on the language/impl. whether they are stored column-wise or row-wise in memory). In your example above, note that you use `j` and `i` for loop variables but `x` and `y` when accessing the index in the buffer, so this probably confused me into thinking you jumped in 0, 5, 10, ..., 1, 6, 11, ... index style.

Comment: @dfri sry, my bad, yeah, I wish it were that, would easily give performance jump :( There are quite a few projects in github but none I tried werent up to date, didnt fit my purpose, or were slow.

Comment: I believe the [following Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3126340/ci-filter-to-create-black-white-image) should be able to instruct you sufficiently to use a `CIFilter` solution (which should be faster than your own manual one) for a purely black and white (and not grayscale) filter.

Comment: @dfri  I'll give it a shot, I seem to have missed that question because it was in objective c, I'll update on how it goes

Comment: @Rob very good point, I didn't know xcode used diff optimizations for debug-release. Thanks. And yes I am using similar values for comparison

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A couple of observations:

1. Make sure you're doing a test on a device with a release build (or optimizations turned off). That alone makes it much faster. On iPhone 7+ it reduced the conversion of 1920 x 1080 pixel color image to grayscale from 1.7 seconds to less than 0.1 seconds.
2. You might want to use `DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform` to process pixels concurrently. On my iPhone 7+, that made it about twice as fast.

In my experience Core Image filters weren't much faster, but you can contemplate vImage or Metal if you need it much faster. But unless you're dealing with extraordinarily large images, the response time with optimized (and possibly concurrent) simple Swift code might be sufficient.

An unrelated observation:

3. Also, I'm not sure how your conversion to black and white works, but often you'd want to calculate the [relative luminance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_luminance) of the color pixel (e.g. 0.2126 * red + 0.7152 * green + 0.0722 * blue). Certainly when converting color image to grayscale you'd do something like that to get an image that more closely represents what the human eye can see, and I'd personally do something like that if converting to black and white, too.

---

FYI, my Swift 3/4 color-to-grayscale routine looks like:

```
func blackAndWhite(image: UIImage, completion: @escaping (UIImage?) -> Void) {
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
        // get information about image

        let imageref = image.cgImage!
        let width = imageref.width
        let height = imageref.height

        // create new bitmap context

        let bitsPerComponent = 8
        let bytesPerPixel = 4
        let bytesPerRow = width * bytesPerPixel
        let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
        let bitmapInfo = Pixel.bitmapInfo
        let context = CGContext(data: nil, width: width, height: height, bitsPerComponent: bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow: bytesPerRow, space: colorSpace, bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo)!

        // draw image to context

        let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: CGFloat(width), height: CGFloat(height))
        context.draw(imageref, in: rect)

        // manipulate binary data

        guard let buffer = context.data else {
            print("unable to get context data")
            completion(nil)
            return
        }

        let pixels = buffer.bindMemory(to: Pixel.self, capacity: width * height)

        DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform(iterations: height) { row in
            for col in 0 ..< width {
                let offset = Int(row * width + col)

                let red = Float(pixels[offset].red)
                let green = Float(pixels[offset].green)
                let blue = Float(pixels[offset].blue)
                let alpha = pixels[offset].alpha
                let luminance = UInt8(0.2126 * red + 0.7152 * green + 0.0722 * blue)
                pixels[offset] = Pixel(red: luminance, green: luminance, blue: luminance, alpha: alpha)
            }
        }

        // return the image

        let outputImage = context.makeImage()!
        completion(UIImage(cgImage: outputImage, scale: image.scale, orientation: image.imageOrientation))
    }
}

struct Pixel: Equatable {
    private var rgba: UInt32

    var red: UInt8 {
        return UInt8((rgba >> 24) & 255)
    }

    var green: UInt8 {
        return UInt8((rgba >> 16) & 255)
    }

    var blue: UInt8 {
        return UInt8((rgba >> 8) & 255)
    }

    var alpha: UInt8 {
        return UInt8((rgba >> 0) & 255)
    }

    init(red: UInt8, green: UInt8, blue: UInt8, alpha: UInt8) {
        rgba = (UInt32(red) << 24) | (UInt32(green) << 16) | (UInt32(blue) << 8) | (UInt32(alpha) << 0)
    }

    static let bitmapInfo = CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedLast.rawValue | CGBitmapInfo.byteOrder32Little.rawValue

    static func ==(lhs: Pixel, rhs: Pixel) -> Bool {
        return lhs.rgba == rhs.rgba
    }
}
```

Clearly, if you want to convert it to absolute black and white, then adjust the algorithm accordingly, but this illustrates a concurrent image buffer manipulation routine.

---

While the above is reasonably fast (again, in optimized release builds), using vImage is even faster. The following is adapted from [Converting Color Images to Grayscale](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/vimage/converting_color_images_to_grayscale):

```
func grayscale(of image: UIImage) -> UIImage? {
    guard var source = sourceBuffer(for: image) else { return nil }

    defer { free(source.data) }

    var destination = destinationBuffer(for: source)

    // Declare the three coefficients that model the eye's sensitivity
    // to color.
    let redCoefficient: Float = 0.2126
    let greenCoefficient: Float = 0.7152
    let blueCoefficient: Float = 0.0722

    // Create a 1D matrix containing the three luma coefficients that
    // specify the color-to-grayscale conversion.
    let divisor: Int32 = 0x1000
    let fDivisor = Float(divisor)

    var coefficients = [
        Int16(redCoefficient * fDivisor),
        Int16(greenCoefficient * fDivisor),
        Int16(blueCoefficient * fDivisor)
    ]

    // Use the matrix of coefficients to compute the scalar luminance by
    // returning the dot product of each RGB pixel and the coefficients
    // matrix.
    let preBias: [Int16] = [0, 0, 0, 0]
    let postBias: Int32 = 0

    let result = vImageMatrixMultiply_ARGB8888ToPlanar8(
        &source,
        &destination,
        &coefficients,
        divisor,
        preBias,
        postBias,
        vImage_Flags(kvImageNoFlags))

    guard result == kvImageNoError else { return nil }

    defer { free(destination.data) }

    // Create a 1-channel, 8-bit grayscale format that's used to
    // generate a displayable image.
    var monoFormat = vImage_CGImageFormat(
        bitsPerComponent: 8,
        bitsPerPixel: 8,
        colorSpace: Unmanaged.passRetained(CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray()),
        bitmapInfo: CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.none.rawValue),
        version: 0,
        decode: nil,
        renderingIntent: .defaultIntent)

    // Create a Core Graphics image from the grayscale destination buffer.
    let cgImage = vImageCreateCGImageFromBuffer(&destination,
                                                &monoFormat,
                                                nil,
                                                nil,
                                               vImage_Flags(kvImageNoFlags),
                                               nil)?.takeRetainedValue()
    return cgImage.map { UIImage(cgImage: $0) }
}


func sourceBuffer(for image: UIImage) -> vImage_Buffer? {
    guard let cgImage = image.cgImage else { return nil }

    let bitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedLast.rawValue).union(.byteOrder32Big)

    var format = vImage_CGImageFormat(bitsPerComponent: 8,
                                      bitsPerPixel: 32,
                                      colorSpace: Unmanaged.passRetained(CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()),
                                      bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo,
                                      version: 0,
                                      decode: nil,
                                      renderingIntent: .defaultIntent)

    var sourceImageBuffer = vImage_Buffer()
    vImageBuffer_InitWithCGImage(&sourceImageBuffer,
                                 &format,
                                 nil,
                                 cgImage,
                                 vImage_Flags(kvImageNoFlags))

    return sourceImageBuffer

func destinationBuffer(for sourceBuffer: vImage_Buffer) -> vImage_Buffer {
    var destinationBuffer = vImage_Buffer()

    vImageBuffer_Init(&destinationBuffer,
                      sourceBuffer.height,
                      sourceBuffer.width,
                      8,
                      vImage_Flags(kvImageNoFlags))

    return destinationBuffer
}
```

Comment: yup release build did the trick, even for my whole routine, the time spent is negligible now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The vImage conversion to 1 bit is vImageConvert_Planar8ToPlanar1. I recommend using one of the dithered options. You will need to convert your RGB image to grayscale first. In principle, this is vImageMatrixMultiply_ARGB8888ToPlanar8(), though really it probably should involve some more sophisticated colorspace conversion rather than a simple matrix.

If all this sounds too complicated, just use vImageConvert_AnyToAny and it should do the right thing.