# Compile each .metal file into a separate .metallib

Tags: xcode, shader, metal

I would like to override the default Xcode Metal compiler behaviour of compiling all project `.metal` files into a single `default.metallib` and instead compile each `.metal` file into a separate `.metallib` file.

However I cannot see how to approach this; can anyone provide a lead?

Xcode version: 10.1

Comment: I added Xcode 11 solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58451581/how-to-compile-two-versions-of-metal-files/58462401#58462401

Comment: @MarekH Nice one, thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I achieved this in two steps:

1) Add a custom build rule for `.metal` files that compiles them individually into `.metallib`s:

[image]

2) Add a custom build step for copying those `.metallib`s into your target:

[image]

Comment: This will also prevent Xcode from creating a default metallib.

Comment: Brilliant!  Thanks.

Comment: Change that to `cp "${DERIVED_FILES_DIR}"/*.metallib "${METAL_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIR}"` if the path contains spaces.