# Compile multiple .metal shader files into a single one

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, metal, core-image

I'm using a script to compile multiple .metal files in one .metallib, something very similar to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/54921611/541016.
It works, but I noticed a strange thing:

- If apply two CIKernel from two different .metal files on the same CIImage, it works as expected
- If apply two CIColorKernel from two different .metal files on the same CIImage, something is wrong and the final output is damaged (I can't also see the preview with xcode)
  Is this a bug from Apple? I don't get why the problem is only related to ColorKernels.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Are you really compiling your multiple `.metal` files into _one_ `.metallib`? I'm asking because in my answer that you linked I was compiling each file into its own `.metallib`.

Comment: well, not sure about it actually. Doesn't XCode support only one .metallib file?

Comment: When you use the default toolchain that Xcode is applying to `.metal` files, yes. But in the linked setup I replaced the build rules with custom steps to build each `.metal` into its own `.metallib`. Do you get a log message when the rendering fails?